# c# Form.Show() does not paint labels in the form to show, ShowDialog() do it

Tags: c#, winforms, show

I call `form1.Show()` method on a WinForm with only a label in it, when the form is showed at the place where the label must be is showed a hole in `form1` (I can see the form under the form1).
If I call `form1.ShowDialog()` this issue doesn't apply, and the label is visible.
Transparency key is set to VisualStudio default.
The problem is I have to call `form1.Show()` and not `ShowDialog()` because the caller form (`mainForm`) have to work in background, then have to close programmatically `form1`.
Any idea on what can be the problem and how to resolve it?

my code:
`mainWindows.cs`:

```
    private void mainWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {           
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Stai terminando la sessione, vuoi fare un backup?", "Fine Sessione", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
            { 
                 backupData(false);
            }
            else if(res == DialogResult.No)
            {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.Enabled = false;
            closer cl = new closer(); //closer is Form1 in the question

            cl.Show();

            backupData(true);
            this.Enabled = true;
            cl.Close();

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
            else
               e.Cancel = true;
   }
```

`closer.cs` is a simple Form, generated by Visual Studio, with only one label added by me via WYSIWYG.

`backupData()` is a method that ZIPs some dirs to a file.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Can you provide a code snippet so that your problem can be reproduced?

Comment: I'm guessing you are inadvertantly calling `form1.Show()` from a different thread.

Comment: in `mainForm.cs`: `Form1 f1 = new Form1(); f1.Show(); backupData(); f1.Close();`, `backupData` is a function that requires a variable amount of time, so with `Form1` I want to inform the user that the App is not responding for this reason. `Form1` is a simple form with a `label` in the center, `TopMost = true;` and `FormBorderStyle` set to none.

Comment: Please show some of your code here.

Comment: now, reviewing my code, I think the problem may be caused by the `MessageBox.Show()` called prior to `cl.Show()`, because, the message box remains in "the middle" between `mainWindow` and `closer`... still don't know how to resolve the issue...

Comment: If `backupData()` is a blocking method, `cl.Show()` may not have the time to paint. Try calling `cl.Refresh()` after showing it.

Comment: @Jimi, that's it! now it works! great!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Application.Run(new closer())`; instead of `new closer().Show()`.

Comment: run is different it will block execution

Answer (score 0):

I decisely changed approach to the problem, I ported the `backupData()` function into the `closer` Form, so now I can call `backupData()` trough a `BackgroundWorker` and also fill a `ProgressBar`, so now I call:

```
   closer cl = new closer();
   cl.ShowDialog();
   if(cl.GetResult())
      this.Close();
```

`GetResult()` returns a bool that returns `backupData()` success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give time to the form to paint all its controls (it will not do so unless you manually tell it to, or the UI thread is idle). You can call `Refresh`... something like:

```
 cl.Show();
 cl.Refresh();
 backupData(true);
 this.Enabled = true;
 cl.Close();
```